# How to do a optional regexp match in Go

Tags: regex, go

Say I have the following two types of string inputs:

```
1) "feat: this is a feature"
2) "feat[JIRA-xxxx]: this is Jira feature
```

The strings contains three parts, there `feat` is Type, `JIRA-xxx` inside `[]` is optional Jira story id, and rest part after `:` is subject.

I want to use a single regexp to match the three parts, optional file should get nil if not present. The following is my code:

```
var re *regexp.Regexp
re = regexp.MustCompile("^(\\w*)(\\[(.*)\\])?\\:\\s(.*)$")

input := "feat[JIRA-xxxx]: this is Jira feature"
res := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(input, -1)
fmt.Print("%q", res)
```

My regular expression has a problem. Because the Jira ID part is optional, I have to use `()?`, but `()` has the other meaning of returning matched value, so with my code, it returns four matches:

```
`feat`, `[JIRA-xxx]`, JIRA-xxx`, `this is Jira feature`
```

How to modify the expression so that I get only the intended 3 matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `?:` modifier to create a non capturing group:

```
re = regexp.MustCompile("^(\\w*)(?:\\[(.*)\\])?\\:\\s(.*)$")
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wZiP5RvWchU).

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly I'm looking for.